# Google Analytics android app to track source install

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am creating a simple mobile app for testing Google Analytics system.
It consists of 1 Activity
And i am installing Google Tag Manager SDK.
It's work.
But i want to configure and testing source traffic.

What i must change in code?
AndroidManifest? Main Activity? How?
And **how i can testing to ensure what it's good work**
For example:<> user came from FaceBook, and i want to see in Google Analytics report
utm_source - FaceBook, utm_medium - cpc
Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?  You may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: im read this. But im use a Google Tag Manager. not Google Analytics directly. What i must to read that to configure to track source traffic?